# Using an existing API with codeigniter 2

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, oop, libraries

I dont ask many questions as I like to research for myself but this has me stumped.
I have an existing Codeigniter2(CI) application and am trying to integrate an existing API for a payment system (MangoPay). I have added it as a library and also preloaded it in autoload.php, it is being included with no errors.
My question is about setting up the class structure and addressing the class from my application.

Now, if you were to get this working from a plain old PHP file, the code would look like this (and btw it works on my machine with no issue from a plain php file)

```
<?php 
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');
$mangoPayApi = new MangoPay\MangoPayApi();
$mangoPayApi->Config->ClientId = 'user_id';
$mangoPayApi->Config->ClientPassword = 'password_here';
$mangoPayApi->Config->TemporaryFolder = 'c:\\wamp\\tmp/';

$User = new MangoPay\UserNatural();
$User->Email = "test_natural@testmangopay.com";
$User->FirstName = "Bob";
$User->LastName = "Briant";
$User->Birthday = 121271;
$User->Nationality = "FR";
$User->CountryOfResidence = "ZA";
$result = $mangoPayApi->Users->Create($User);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

So, I have created a new class in the libraries folder and if i was to var_dump() the contents of mangoPayApi as below, it throws all kinds of stuff which proves that it is working (ie no PHP errors).

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
require_once('/vendor/autoload.php');
class MangoPayService {

    private $mangoPayApi;
private $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->mangoPayApi = new MangoPay\MangoPayApi();
        $this->mangoPayApi->Config->ClientId = 'user_id_here';
        $this->mangoPayApi->Config->ClientPassword = 'password_here';
        $this->mangoPayApi->Config->TemporaryFolder = 'c:\\wamp\\tmp/';    
        //var_dump($mangoPayApi);
    }
```

I thought I could just write a method in the class like this

```
function add_user(){
        //CREATE NATURAL USER

            $this->user = new user();
            $user->Email = 'test_natural@testmangopay.com';
            $user->FirstName = "John";
            $user->LastName = "Smith";
            $user->Birthday = 121271;
            $user->Nationality = "FR";
            $user->CountryOfResidence = "ZA";

        $add_userResult = $this->mangoPayApi->Users->Create($user);
        var_dump($add_userResult);
    }
```

and acces it in my application like

```
<?php echo $this->mangopayservice->add_user() ?>
```

But i get errors  Fatal error: Class 'user' not found in C:\wamp\www\mpapp\application\libraries\MangoPayService.php on line 25 (which is this->user = new user(); this line)

Can anyone explain how to correctly set up this scenario and how to integrate correctly with the API.

if I can get something to create a user simply when a page is opened, I think I can work it from there using the solution as a roadmap.

I will be writing all the integration code once I understand how to make this work.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MangoPay requires a `NaturalUser` class. You try to instantiate a `user` class.

Simply replace your first line of the `add_user` function with :

```
$user = new MangoPay\UserNatural();
```

Comment: i am michiel, I could kiss you...or at least buy you a beer or three. Thank you so much. You are a diamond :D